# How to export the codebase from one Accurev server to another Accurev server?

Tags: accurev

we have 2 Accurev servers having same stream name,some develoopers are working on One accurev server with "ABC" stream and another developers are working on another Accurv server with "ABC" Stream,at the end of the day the second accurrev server changes has to be exported to first Accurev Server Stream.Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccuRev does not have an export/import tool that will migrate data from one depot to another.  Basically, you will copy the code from Depot1/StreamABC into a workspace in Depot2/StreamABC and keep/promote.